# spacing between lines/paragraphs with tikz

Tags: spacing

I know that when I include graphs/`tikz`, first LaTeX calculate the space needed for the graph. If there is not enough space, it pushes the graph to the next page. And to make the first page looks *nicer*, it automatically sets the space between lines/paragraphs. Is there a way to stop this? Something tells me it is a quick/short command :( but I can't find it. 
As you can see in the picture, the spacing is not nice at all.

Thank you.

Also, can someone show me the way to copy and paste my LaTeX code so that it appears legible in this Ask Question box? Thanks.

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{ tikz, pgfplots}

\linespread{1.25}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}

\section{LaTeX Spacing Issues}

\lipsum[1]

%\begin{example}
\textbf{Main Example:}
several texts and equations here. It seems that if there is not enough space for the graph, then LaTeX automatically adjust the space between lines/graphs. 

\[y = x\]
Another equation, 
\[y = x^2\]

\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=0.07cm]
  \def\xmin{0}
  \def\xmax{10}
  \def\ymin{0}
  \def\ymax{120}

  % grid
\draw[style=help lines, ystep=10, xstep=1] (\xmin,\ymin) grid (\xmax,\ymax);

  % axes
  \draw[->] (\xmin,\ymin) -- coordinate (x axis mid) (\xmax+.5,\ymin) node[below] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (\xmin,\ymin) -- coordinate (y axis mid) (\xmin,\ymax+5) node[left] {$y$};

  % xticks and yticks
  \foreach \x in { 1, 2, ..., 10}
    \node at (\x, \ymin) [below] {\x};
  \foreach \y in {20, 40, ..., 120}
    \node at (\xmin,\y) [left] {\y};t
    \draw[scale=1,domain=0:10,smooth,variable=\x,blue, thick] plot ({\x},{12*\x});

\foreach \Point in {(1,12), (2,24), (3,36), (4,48), (5,60), (6,72), (7, 84)}{
    \node at \Point {\textbullet};
\node[below=.5cm] at (x axis mid) {Number of visitors};    
\node[left=.8cm,rotate=90] at (y axis mid) {Money taken };
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
%\end{example}

\subsection*{New section}
\lipsum[1]
```

Comment: There is \vfill\pagebreak[3]

Comment: Put `\raggedbottom` in preamble.

Comment: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863)

Comment: never leave a blank line before `\[` or have one `\[` immediately after the previous `\]`, the vertical spacing will always be wrong. Don't put the tikzpicture in `\[` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `book` class inserts `flushbottom` by default in an attempt to make the last line of each page to be at the bottom. This can be prevented by issuing `\raggedbottom` in the preamble.

```
.
.
.
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
.
.
.
```

[image]

However, since you are inserting a picture, you better not use the display math mode in this case. Instead of `\[....\]`, you can use `figure` environment and let the picture float. This way you are making use of abilities of latex in placing pictures. Also, with `figure` environment comes `\caption` macro which you can use for a short description of the picture and what more, you can insert a `\label` and refer to this picture else where.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{ tikz, pgfplots}

\linespread{1.25}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{cancel}

\raggedbottom
\begin{document}

\section{LaTeX Spacing Issues}

\lipsum[1]

%\begin{example}
\textbf{Main Example:}
several texts and equations here. It seems that if there is not enough space for the graph, then LaTeX automatically adjust the space between lines/graphs.
%% no blank line be left here
\[y = x\]
Another equation,
\[y = x^2\]
%% no blank line be left here
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=0.07cm]
  \def\xmin{0}
  \def\xmax{10}
  \def\ymin{0}
  \def\ymax{120}

  % grid
\draw[style=help lines, ystep=10, xstep=1] (\xmin,\ymin) grid (\xmax,\ymax);

  % axes
  \draw[->] (\xmin,\ymin) -- coordinate (x axis mid) (\xmax+.5,\ymin) node[below] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (\xmin,\ymin) -- coordinate (y axis mid) (\xmin,\ymax+5) node[left] {$y$};

  % xticks and yticks
  \foreach \x in { 1, 2, ..., 10}
    \node at (\x, \ymin) [below] {\x};
  \foreach \y in {20, 40, ..., 120}
    \node at (\xmin,\y) [left] {\y};t
    \draw[scale=1,domain=0:10,smooth,variable=\x,blue, thick] plot ({\x},{12*\x});

\foreach \Point in {(1,12), (2,24), (3,36), (4,48), (5,60), (6,72), (7, 84)}{
    \node at \Point {\textbullet};
\node[below=.5cm] at (x axis mid) {Number of visitors};
\node[left=.8cm,rotate=90] at (y axis mid) {Money taken };
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{This is a nice picture}
\end{figure}
%\end{example}

\subsection*{New section}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]